# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 on update

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function and it works fine, if I only have one parameter.
But if I have more than one I get the above error.

`version for the right syntax to use near 'usr_lastname','usr_login'='firstname','lastname' at line 1 in`

```
public function updateById($id, $data)
{
    #print_r($data);
    foreach ($data as $field => $value){
        $fields[] = '`'.$field.'`';
        $targets[] = ':'.$field;
        $values[] = $value;
    }

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE ".$this->table." SET ".join(',', $fields)."=".join(',', $targets)." WHERE id = $id");

    foreach ($targets as $pos => $target){
        switch (true){
            case is_int($values[$pos]) : $type = PDO::PARAM_INT; break;
            case is_bool($values[$pos]) : $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL; break;
            case is_string($values[$pos]) : $type = PDO::PARAM_STR; break;
            case is_null($values[$pos]) : $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL; break;
            default : $type = PDO::PARAM_STR; break;
        }


        $stmt->bindValue($target, $values[$pos], $type);
        print_r($stmt);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $json = array(
        'success' => true,
        'result' => $value
    );
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

I don´t see any "," error.

Any suggestions what I´m going wrong or missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
SET ".join(',', $fields)."=".join(',', $targets)."
```

syntax for UPDATE is like this:

```
col1 = :col1, col2 = :col2, col3 = :col3 ...
```

for now your code do it like this:

```
col1,col2,col3 = :col1, :col2, :col3
```

so if you have only 1 parameter it works fine (col1 = :col1)

Easiest solution would be to change the way you prepare `$fields` and `$targets` for example:

```
foreach ($data as $field){
    $updateFields[] = '`'.$field.'` = '.':'.$field
}
```

THen your SQL should be like this:

```
"UPDATE ".$this->table." SET ".join(',', $updateFields)." WHERE id = $id"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark!
That solved my problem and and shortend the code in the Update query!